# Disable header check for inflating in SvZlib

Tags: silverlight-4.0, zlib, inflate-exception

I am using SvZlib for Silverlight 4 and try to inflate bytes array by using:

```
Cellbi.SvZLib.Utils.Decompress(bytesArray);
```

But I get error "incorrect header check". I am looking for disabling header check, but no results.

Any idea how to disable header check for decompressing (input array does not contain any header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think that disabling the header check will help?  All you can do is tell zlib that it is raw deflate data that has no header.  If that is not the case, then all that will do is result in a different error.

What are the first several bytes of the data?  You are probably trying to decode gzip data using a zlib decoder, or zlib data using a gzip decoder.